# Why is my <i> tag being appended multiple times for each click as I click the add button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a Todo list using HTML, CSS and jQuery. So basically when the person types an activity and presses the '+' button it gets added to the list along with a 'Delete'(Font Awesome Recycle Bin) icon so that the user can delete the activity. I have implemented this using the .append() function. However, when a user adds the first item there is one delete button. However for every other list the number of delete buttons multiply. (Eg. when the user adds the second item there are two delete buttons for that item, and when they add the third item there are three delete buttons for that item). I can't understand why this is happening and what is the best way to fix this?

I have used .append() on the .listInput and appended the .newItem. 
I have then used .append() on the .newItem and appended the  can icon.

```js
$(".enter").click(function() {
  var $item = $('input[name=add]').val();
  if ($item.length > 0) {
    $(".listInput").append('<li class="newItem animated fadeIn">' + $item + '</li>');
    $('.newItem').append('<i class="animated fadeIn far fa-trash-alt fa-1x"></i>');
  } else {
    alert("Enter an acitvity to add");
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="takeInput">
  <input type="text" name="add" value="Add Your Item Here">
  <i class="enter fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
</div>

<ul class="listInput">
</ul>
```

I want only one trash icon for each list item.

Comment: issue is with the code  if ($item.length > 0) {
    $(".listInput").append('<li class="newItem animated fadeIn">' + $item + '</li>');
    $('.newItem').append('<i class="animated fadeIn far fa-trash-alt fa-1x"></i>');
  } as you are appending same element again

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That fixed the issue of the multiple replications of the trash can but now the trashcan icon does not get deleted when I click the trashcan. Only the list item gets deleted.

This is the code I have used for deleting the list item:
$('.listInput').on('click', '.newItem', function() {
    $(this).hide('2000', function() {
       $(this).remove();
    });
    
  })

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('.newItem').append()` will append something to *all* elements with the class `newItem`, not just the one you just added. To fix that just use a single append:

```js
$(".enter").click(function() {
  var $item = $('input[name=add]').val();
  if ($item.length > 0) {
    $(".listInput").append('<li class="newItem animated fadeIn">' + $item + '<i class="animated fadeIn far fa-trash-alt fa-1x"></i></li>');
  } else {
    alert("Enter an acitvity to add");
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="takeInput">
  <input type="text" name="add" value="Add Your Item Here">
  <i class="enter fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
</div>

<ul class="listInput">
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes this makes perfect sense, Now I see what the problem was. Thank you so much. The solution you provided above resolved the issue. :D

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
var $item = $('input[name="add"]').val();
```

Comment: Yes I have already done that as you can see in my code snippet above. The solution provided by @j08691 worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $('.newItem') refers to any element that has that class. For example, if you have five items on the list they will all have the class new item. If you were to add another item (that makes six items), then you are adding a bin icon to each element with class 'newItem'

Comment: Yes now I understood what the problem was. Thank you so much. So I have to use just one append() and put the icon within the <li> tag.

Comment: Yes, that would fix the problem! If you need any more help just let me know :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".enter").click(function() {
  var $item = $('input[name=add]').val();
  if ($item.length > 0) {
    $(".listInput").append('<li class="newItem animated fadeIn">' + $item + '</li>' + '<i class="animated fadeIn far fa-trash-alt fa-1x"></i>');
  } else {
    alert("Enter an acitvity to add");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".enter").click(function() {
  let item = $('input[name=add]').val();
  let li = $('<li class="newItem animated fadeIn"/>');
  let iconTrash = $('<i style="margin-left:1em;" class="animated fadeIn far fa-trash-alt fa-1x"/>')
  if (item.length >= 0) {
  li.append(item,iconTrash)
    $(".listInput").append(li);
  } else {
    alert("Enter an acitvity to add");
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="takeInput">
  <input type="text" name="add" value="Add Your Item Here">
  <i class="enter fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
</div>

<ul class="listInput">
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot. :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the trash icon is added to all the elements that have the class **'newItem'**. So you have to create a **li(list item)** element and append it to the **ul(unordered list)** element. Then create the icon and append it to the created list item element. You can create element using the **document.createElement(tagName)** function. and append it using javascript or jquery